# Finding $f$ from the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x) + f(y) + e^{x+y}(x+y)-xe^x-ye^y+2xy$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

The question asks us to find the function $f(x)$ with the given information:

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f'(0)=1$ and $f(x+y)=f(x) + f(y) + e^{x+y}(x+y)-xe^x-ye^y+2xy$ where $x,y \in\mathbb R$. Then determine $f(x)$.

Also, it will be great if someone could explain the general approach used in such questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why was m0nhawk's edit suggestion rejected?

Comment: Whats is (e^x .e^y ) ?

Comment: I could not somehow write e to the power x+y . So just wrote it in another way.

Comment: What class would give something like this for homework?

Comment: Just  before starting with Differential equations , functional equations were taught. This was one of the tougher questions as there is no symmetry involved or cannot be solved graphically either. So I wanted to know if there is a general approach to these questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put $x = y = 0$:
$$
f(0) = 2f(0)
$$
so $f(0) = 0$.

Next, differentiate the original equation with respect to $y$ alone:
$$
f'(x + y) = f'(y) + e^{x+y} + (x+y)e^{x+y} - e^y - ye^y + 2x.
$$
Put $y = 0$:
$$
f'(x) = f'(0) + e^x + xe^x - 1 + 2x = e^x + xe^x + 2x
$$
Therefore
$$
f(x) = \int_0^x \left(e^z + ze^z + 2z\right) dz.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the equation as 
$f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)=e^{x+y}(x+y)-xe^x-ye^y-2xy$
then simply note that
$f(x)=x e^x-x^2$
does the trick.