# Finding $f(x)$ from the functional equation $f(x+2y)=f(x)+f(2y)+e^{x+2y}(x+2y)-xe^x-2ye^{2y}+4xy$

Tags: calculus, functions

This sum really looks scary to me. No idea how to begin. I just figured out that $f(0)$ is $0$. What's next?

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, such that $f'(0)=1$ and
> $$f(x+2y)=f(x)+f(2y)+e^{x+2y}(x+2y)-xe^x-2ye^{2y}+4xy$$
> for all real $x$ and $y$. Find $f(x)$.

P.S. Please don't use very high level maths.

Comment: No it is $x^2+xe^x$ @anubhav

Comment: look here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455543/finding-a-function-from-the-given-functional-equation?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Set $y = h/2$ and $g(x) = xe^x$, then
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h = \frac{f(h)}h + \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h
-e^{h}+2x
$$
Now take the limit for $h \to 0$ (and use $f(0)=0$ which you already obtained):
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}h \to f'(x) \, , \quad \frac{f(h)}h = \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h-0} \to f'(0) \, , \quad \text{etc.}
$$

It follows that
$$
 f'(x) = f'(0) + g'(x) - 1 + 2x = g'(x) +2x \, .
$$

Together with $f(0) = 0$ it follows that
$f(x) = g(x) + x^2 = xe^x + x^2$.

Comment: It looks like $f'(0)=1$ comes from nowhere.

Comment: @A.G., it is stated in the question.

Comment: @A.G.: Thanks for the feedback, I have tried to improve it.

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks, I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Partial differentiating the given equation w.r.t x keeping y constant we get
$$ f'(x+2y)=f'(x)+ e^{x+2y}(x+2y)+e^{x+2y}-e^x-e^xx+4y$$
Now put $x=0$ and $y=x/2$ to get
$$ f'(x)=e^xx+e^x+2x $$
Now integrate both sides and find the constant by putting $x=0$ to get $$ f(x)=xe^x+x^2 $$

Comment: Can you tell me why you used partial differentiation?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I really don't know the reason. It is something that I read somewhere and I was able to solve almost all the functional equation problems.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I prefer to replace $2y$ with $y$ to obtain

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+(x+y)e^{x+y}-xe^x-ye^{y}+2xy \tag{1}$$

Next, choose $x=y$ to obtain

$$f(2x)=2f(x)+2xe^{2x}-2xe^{x}+2x^2 \tag{2}$$

Or equivalently

$$\begin{align}
& f(2x)-2f(x)=(2xe^{2x}+(2x)^2)-2(xe^x+x^2) \\
& f'(0)=1
\end{align}
\tag{3}$$

Now, I will prove that the only function satisfying $(3)$ is

$$f(x)=xe^x+x^2 \tag{4}$$

which is suggestive when looking at $(3)$.

Suppose that there is another function called $g(x)$ satisfying

$$\begin{align}
& g(2x)-2g(x)=(2xe^{2x}+(2x)^2)-2(xe^x+x^2) \\
& g'(0)=1
\end{align}
\tag{5}$$

Next, introducing $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ we conclude that

$$\begin{align}
& h(2x)=2h(x) \\
& h'(0)=0
\end{align}
\tag{6}$$

and so $h(x)=0$ leading to $f(x)=g(x)$. For a proof of $h(x)=0$ on $\mathbb R$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592473/if-f2x-2fx-f0-0-then-fx-0).

Comment: *" you can easily observe that ..."* ? – That is a possible solution, but for uniqueness you need  the condition $f'(0)=1$  here, so that part might need a bit more explanation.

Comment: @MartinR: you are right, but I just compared the LHS and the RHS. I just forgot the condition $f'(0)=1$! :)

Comment: @MartinR: Can equation $(3)$ have any other solutions? I mean regardless of the condition $f'(0)=1$, what are the functions satisfying $(3)$?

Comment: $xe^x + x^2 + ax$ for any $a \in \Bbb R$ would satisfy (3) as well.

Comment: So that will be the point! :) Thanks. :)

Comment: You still have not *proved* that $xe^x + x^2 + Cx$ are the only solutions to $(3)$.