# Solve the functional equation $f(xy)=e^{xy-x-y} \big( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \big)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f: \Bbb R ^+ \to  \Bbb R$ satisfies $$f(xy)=e^{xy-x-y} \big( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \big)$$ for all $x, y \ge 0$ and if $f'(1)=e$, determine $f(x)$.

I'm a beginner. Can someone give me some hints for this sum?

I'm getting $f(1)=0$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: You mention $f'(1)$. Is $f$ derivable just in $1$, or everywhere?

Comment: @MathJack, I've edited your question assuming that you meant () instead of {} in the functional equation. Please tell us if I am right (and note that { and } have a special meaning in LaTeX).

Comment: @AlexM. I don't know whether its derivable everywhere....its not mentioned in question...

Comment: Since some notations are not standard, does $\Bbb R ^+$ include $0$ or not?

Comment: According the Wikipedia definition 0 should not be included.But truly speaking I don't know whether the question assumes that. @AlexM.

Comment: @AlexM.  Thanks for your edit.  Then everything looks right.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  f(xy)&=e^{xy-x-y} \left( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \right) \\
  f(1) &= e^0 f(1) + e^0 f(1) \\
  f(1) &= 0
\end{align*}
If $x>0$, set $y = \frac{x+h}{x}$, then $xy=x+h$.
\begin{align*}
  f(xy)&= f(x+h) \\
  &= e^{x\frac{x+h}{x}-x-\frac{x+h}{x}} \left( e^\frac{x+h}{x} f(x)+e^xf(\frac{x+h}{x}) \right) \\
  &= e^{h-\frac{x+h}{x}} \left( e^\frac{x+h}{x} f(x)+e^xf(\frac{x+h}{x}) \right) \\
&=e^h f(x) + e^{x+h-\frac{x+h}{x}} f(1+\frac{h}{x})
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} &= \frac{(e^h - 1) f(x) + e^{x+h-\frac{x+h}{x}} f(1+\frac{h}{x})}{h} \\
  &= \frac{e^h - 1}{h} f(x) + \frac{e^{x+h-\frac{x+h}{x}}}{x} \frac{f(1+\frac{h}{x}) - f(1)}{\frac{h}{x}}
\end{align*}
Since $f'(1) = e$, take limit on both sides as $h \to 0$.
\begin{align*}
  f'(x) &= f(x) + \frac{e^{x-1}}{x} f'(1) \\
  &= f(x) + \frac{e^x}{x} \\
  &= f(x) + \frac{e^{x}}{x}
\end{align*}
Let $y = f(x)$.
\begin{align*}
  y'-y &= \frac{e^{x}}{x} \\
  (y e^{-x})' &= \frac{1}{x} \\
  y e^{-x} &= \ln x + C \\
  y &= e^{x} \ln x + C e^x
\end{align*}
Since $y = f(1) = 0, C = 0$.  Hence $y = e^{x} \ln x \forall x > 0$.

#### Alternative method

I followed Sanchayan Dutta's method.

Why can we do a partial differentiation w.r.t. $x$?

We keep $y$ *constant*, and treat $x$ as the *only* independent variable.

Looking at the calucations Sanchayan Dutta's answer, I was puzzled and I wondered where the term $e^{xy}$ was.  Why are our calculations so *different*?  Why can we get the *right* answer despite *different* calculations?  As a result, I decided to do it myself and to add this section.

\begin{equation*}
   f(xy)=e^{xy-x-y} \left( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \right)
\end{equation*}

Partial differentiation with respect to $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
  y f'(xy) &= (y-1) e^{xy-x-y} \left( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \right) + e^{xy-x-y} \left( e^yf'(x)+e^xf(y) \right) \\
  &= e^{xy-x-y} \left( (y-1) e^yf(x)+(y-1) e^xf(y) + e^yf'(x)+e^xf(y) \right) \\
  &= e^{\color{red}{x}(y-1)-y} \left( e^yf'(x) + (y-1) e^yf(x)+y e^xf(y) \right)
\end{align*}

Now, I know why we got *different* calculations but the *same* result: replace $x$ and $y$ by $1$ and $x$ respectively, so the missing $\color{red}{x}$ doesn't affect the result, and we still have

\begin{equation*}
  f'(x)-f(x) = \frac{e^{x}}{x}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Is not $f(1) = e^0f(1)+e^1f(1)$? It's a small error but I don't think it changes the rest of your answer any.

Comment: As it is currently written, the problem has no solution: you have already obtained $f(1) = 0$, so now take $x = 1$ and obtain $f(y) = {\rm e}^{-1} {\rm e}^y f(1) + {\rm e} f(y) = 0 + {\rm e} f(y) = {\rm e} f(y)$, so $f = 0$, which does not satisfy the condition $f'(1) = {\rm e}$.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for your comment, I'm now looking for ways to fix this.

Comment: You can't fix it. I've edited the question according to what I *believe* it was intended to mean.

Comment: @LeeFisher Thanks for your comment.  Edited

Answer (score 2):

On partial differentiating w.r.t $x$ $$f(xy)=e^{xy-x-y} \big( e^yf(x)+e^xf(y) \big)$$

we get

$$yf'(xy)=e^{x(y-1)-y} (e^y f'(x)+e^y (y-1) f(x)+e^x y f(y))$$

Putting $x=1$ and $y=x$ we get :

$$\begin{align*}
  f'(x)-f(x) &= \frac{e^{x}}{x} \\
  f(x) e^{-x} &= \ln x + C \\
  f(x) &= e^{x} \ln x + C e^x \\
\end{align*}$$

Since $$ y = f(1) = 0, C = 0,$$

Hence $$y = e^x\ln(x).$$

Comment: Can you tell why will there be different answer when we put y=0 ?

Comment: "Putting $x=0$ and $y=x$ we get". I have no idea what you're doing after this. If $x=0$ and $y=x$, then $x=0=y$ and I don't see how to get $y'-y= \frac{e^{x}}{x}$. Furthermore $y$ is variable, not a function. You can't differentiate variables.

Comment: @GitGud I tried to follow anubhav http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591441/finding-fx-from-a-functional-equation/1591457#1591457

Comment: @SanchayanDutta In anubhav's answer, the given condition is $f'(0)=1$, so his substitution $x \mapsto 0, y\mapsto x$ will give $f'(0)$.  But the given condition here is $f'(1) = e$, so I *don't* quite really get it.

Comment: @GNUSupporter can this sum be done with that partial derivative method? If yes,how? BTW I did use f'(1)=e

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Though I *can't* give a rigourous proof, I assume that this is legitimate.  (This may be the result of the chain rule in partial differentitation.)  My questions are: (1) How can you get the second equality from the first one?  I tried, and I got terms like $e^{xy-x-y}$, I don't know why $e^{xy}$ vanished.  (2) How can you "put $x=0$ and $y=x$ we get $f'(x)-f(x) = \dfrac{e^{x}}{x}$"?  Such a substitution gives you $f'(0)$.  How do you know what $f'(0)$ is?

Comment: I think I made a mistake there.It should be $x=1$. @GNUSupporter