# If $f(2x)=2f(x)$ and $f'(0)=0$ then $f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

Recently, when I was working on a functional equation, I encountered something **like** an ordinary differential equation with boundary conditions!

> **Theorem**. If the following holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$ 
>   $$\begin{align}
> f(2x) &=2 f(x) \\
> f'(0) &=0
> \end{align}$$
>   then $f(x)=0$ on $\mathbb R$.

Intuitively, it is evident for me that $f(x)=0$ but I cannot show this by a formal argument. In fact, I don't have any idea to work on it! :)

I will be thankful if you provide me a hint or help to show this with a nice formal proof.

Comment: Hint: Try first showing that f(0)=0 using what you've been given.

Comment: $f(x)$ is half $f(2x)$, now keep halving until you reach $0$

Comment: @qwr If you start with $x \ne 0$, when will that happen?

Comment: @user I give idea not formal

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Setting $x=0$ in $f(2x)=2f(x)$, $f(0)=0$.  Now fix $x\neq 0$ and consider the values $f(x/2^n)$.  By induction, $f(x/2^n)=f(x)/2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  But by the definition of the derivative, $$\frac{f(x/2^n)-f(0)}{x/2^n-0}=\frac{f(x)/2^n}{x/2^n}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$$ must converge to $f'(0)=0$ as $n\to\infty$.  It follows that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate the last step please. :) I cannot understand your last step with fractions! :) I mean it seems that the fraction is independent of $n$ and so as $n \to \infty$, it may converge to $\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Comment: The left hand side of the equation is the part that converges to $f'(0)$, since $x/2^n$ converges to $0$.